# How do I avoid a generic error in GDI+ when creating a custom cursor

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, gdi+, mouse-cursor

I am using the following code to generate a bespoke cursor dependent on the mouse position inside a win forms control. The cursor becomes a line that points towards the center of the control. Everything works very well for a few seconds and then I get the very unhelpful message :-

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' in System.Drawing.Common.dll
> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.Common.dll but was not handled in user code
> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

This error appears to be connected to the garbage collector trying to clean up the pointer while it is still in use (though it could be something else).  As you will see I have tried to make the pointer a property so that it isn't cleaned up but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas on how to avoid this error would be very welcome.

```
public struct IconInfo
{
    public bool fIcon;
    public int xHotspot;
    public int yHotspot;
    public IntPtr hbmMask;
    public IntPtr hbmColor;
}


public partial class CursorTest : UserControl
{
    public CursorTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect(ref IconInfo icon);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);        

    bool IsBusy { get; set; } = false;
    IntPtr ptr { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a 32x32 cursor from a bitmap, with the hot spot in the middle
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateCursor(Bitmap bmp)
    {
         ptr = bmp.GetHicon();
        IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
        GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
        tmp.xHotspot = 16;
        tmp.yHotspot = 16;
        tmp.fIcon = false;
        ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(ptr);// Error Happens here
        DestroyIcon(ptr);            
    }

   

    private void GenerateCursorFromPostion(Point e)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Busy!!!");
            return;
        }
        IsBusy = true;
        float x = 16 * (Width / 2.0f - e.X);
        float y = 16 * (Height / 2.0f - e.Y);

        PointF st = new PointF(x + 16, y + 16);
        PointF ed = new PointF(16 - x, 16 - y);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(32, 32);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, st, ed);
        
        CreateCursor(bmp);

        g.Dispose();           
        bmp.Dispose();

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private void CursorTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateCursorFromPostion(e.Location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues with your current code.

Your primary issue appears to be that you are destroying the icon for the cursor. When you create a `Cursor` using a handle, the handle is not copied, but used directly. Instead, you need to dispose it either when the control is being disposed, or when the cursor is replaced with another.

You also need to dispose the handle from `GetHicon`, and the `Bitmap` and `Graphics` needs a `using`, and you need to handle various errors.

```cs
public partial class CursorTest : UserControl
{
    public CursorTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, out IconInfo pIconInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect(in IconInfo icon);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);        

    bool IsBusy { get; set; } = false;
    IntPtr ptr { get; set; }

    protected override Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        DestroyIcon(ptr);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a 32x32 cursor from a bitmap, with the hot spot in the middle
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateCursor(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        var original = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            original = bmp.GetHicon();
            if(!GetIconInfo(original, out var tmp))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            tmp.xHotspot = 16;
            tmp.yHotspot = 16;
            tmp.fIcon = false;
            var newPtr = CreateIconIndirect(in tmp);
            if (newPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            this.Cursor = new Cursor(newPtr);
            DestroyIcon(ptr);
            ptr = newPtr;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(original != IntPtr.Zero)
                DestroyIcon(original);
        }
    }

    private void GenerateCursorFromPostion(Point e)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Busy!!!");
            return;
        }
        IsBusy = true;
        float x = 16 * (Width / 2.0f - e.X);
        float y = 16 * (Height / 2.0f - e.Y);

        PointF st = new PointF(x + 16, y + 16);
        PointF ed = new PointF(16 - x, 16 - y);

        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(32, 32))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, st, ed);
        
            CreateCursor(bmp);
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private void CursorTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateCursorFromPostion(e.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That does the trick. May I ask why you changed the 'ref' in the external calls into 'in' and 'out' respectively.  I also note that Dispose needs to be protected rather than public, but we might be using different .NET versions...

Comment: `ref` means it is supposed to be marshalled in and out, whereas those parameters are not.